# Error coming when testing lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I test the lambda function (lambda function is Hello world) it gives the error mentioned below:

```
 {   "errorMessage": "An error occurred during JSON parsing",   "errorType": "java.lang.RuntimeException",   "stackTrace": [],   "cause": {
    "errorMessage": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of int out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@4520ebad; line: 1, column: 1]",
    "errorType": "java.io.UncheckedIOException",
    "stackTrace": [],
    "cause": {
      "errorMessage": "Can not deserialize instance of int out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@4520ebad; line: 1, column: 1]",
      "errorType": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException",
      "stackTrace": [
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:857)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseInteger(StdDeserializer.java:460)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:309)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:287)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1511)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1102)"
      ]
    }   } }
```

Comment: How does your Lambda look like? Please share the code...

Comment: package HelloWorld.Hello;
import java.util.Map;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context; 
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */

public class App {
 public String myHandler(int myCount , Context context) {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        logger.log("received : " + myCount);
        System.out.println("Hey"+myCount);
        return String.valueOf(myCount);
    }
}